# store wget link into a database (php)

Tags: php, database, flv, wget

I'm trying to find a solution to download automatically .flv link everyday from a website using wget and to store all the links into a database to stream them in my website. (all in php)
How to do that? I don't need to store the files only links into the database.

Best regards,

Comment: You need to be more specific, something like this sounds like you want someone to come in an paste all the code for you, not help you building it.

Comment: I've got this idea only this morning, I just wanted to ask people to tell me the way (step) to do that... I'm in Design not really in code haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you would need wget.

You could use curl to go to the website and get the new link.  After you have the link, just store the information in the database and your done.

You are basically scrapping other sites for content.

This article looks like it is promising:

http://www.merchantos.com/makebeta/php/scraping-links-with-php/

You could also try to search google.  I used the term:

scrapping site php curl

Have fun.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I try to use Dom the day after I post my question but I didn't have what I wanted. And now I'm trying with preg_match_all. I will make a new thread for that.